# Grouped bar chart with date on x-axis

Tags: r, plot

I'm getting back to R, and I have some trouble plotting the data I want.

It's in this format :

```
date         value1    value2
10/25/2016   50        60
12/16/2016   70        80
01/05/2017   35        45
```

And I would like to plot value1 and value2 next to each other, with the corresponding date on the x axis. So far I have this, I tried to plot only value1 first :

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=date,y=value1))
```

But the resulting plot doesn't show anything. The maximum values on the x and y axis seem to correspond to the ranges of my dataframe, but why is nothing showing up?

It works with `plot(df$date,df$value1)` though, so I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the ggplot call alone does not actually create any layers on the plot. You need to add a `geom`.

For this you probably want `geom_point()` or `geom_line()`

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=date,y=value1)) +
  geom_point()
```

or

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=date,y=value1)) +
  geom_line()
```

or you could do both if you want points and lines

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=date,y=value1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

If you want both values on the plot, I would recommend doing some data manipulation first with the `tidyr` package.

```
df %>%
  gather(key = "group", value = "value", value1:value2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, color = group, group = group)) +
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks :) And if I want to have both value1 and value2 at the same time on the plot?

Comment: Added how you can add them both to the plot easily with some minor data manipulation. If you are just getting back into R, and aren't familiar with it, the `%>%` symbol is the pipe and is very common in the `tidyverse`. It can be loaded either directly with the `magrittr` package or from the `dplyr` package